# Reading a text file located in iCloud Shortcuts folder using a Python script on Mac

Tags: icloud, finder, python, shortcuts-app

I am appending text to a file located in Shortcuts folder using a shortcut on iPhone. I want to access the contents of this file from a Python script on Mac like any other text file. I am unable to locate the path of the file. The command `ll ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/` is not listing the Shortcuts folder but is listing the folders I have created in iCloud Drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Shortcuts folder is:

`~/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~is~workflow~my~workflows/Documents`

You can get this path by navigating to the file you want to work with in Finder and right clicking > hold <kbd>Option</kbd> and click "Copy < filename > as Pathname"